# ssh and rsync in one command line from Ruby

Tags: ruby, bash, rsync

I need to write a bash command line that uses ssh to connect to "first_machine" and from here run `rsync` to another machine `remoteuser@10.2.2.150`.

This is my code:

```
first_machine = user@192.16.58.12
cmd="ssh #{first_machine} \"rsync -e\"ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null\" --archive -H /home/user/aaaaa remoteuser@10.2.2.150:/home/remoteuser/\" "

exit_status = system("#{cmd}")
```

I tested the ssh command and also the `rsync` separately. They work fine, so I can do ssh from the machine where I run the Ruby script and:

```
rsync -e"ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" --archive -H /home/user/aaaaa remoteuser@10.2.2.150:/home/remoteuser/
```

works well when launched in the `#{first_machine}` -> folder is copied.

Instead, when I run my code through the Ruby script I receive the error:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender] 
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(605) [sender=3.0.9]
```

This error does not occur if I run the command separately.

Comment: Your first line invalid. Your `"#{cmd}"` is redundant.

Comment: why is redundant? I'm running the ruby script in a different machine then "first_machine"

Comment: So first I need to connect to first_machine and then perform for there rsync

Comment: and also, If I do    cmd="ssh #{first_machine} \" ls -al \"" works perfect. So there is a mistake (???) in the rsync part

Comment: Remember when making shell commands to escape arbitrary arguments or strings with [`shellescape`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellescape). Have you tried using [`net-ssh`](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh) for this? That may give you more control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, fix the user problems pointed out by the Tin Man in the other answer. Do you have public key authentication set up between `first_machine` and the user running the `ruby` script?

Then, look at your quoting and you'll see that the command you're passing to `ssh` consists only of `rsync -e`. Maybe try this:

```
first_machine = 'user@192.16.58.12'
cmd="ssh #{first_machine} \"rsync -e 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null' --archive -H /home/user/aaaaa remoteuser@10.2.2.150:/home/remoteuser/\" "
exit_status = system(cmd)
```

Disclaimer: I've never used Ruby before, but a 2 minute glance at some tutorial sites made it clear you've got syntax errors in your sample code.

Is there a reason not to do this as a bash script?

Comment: Same result doing cmd="ssh #{first_machine} \"rsync -e 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null' --archive -H /home/user/aaaaa remoteuser@10.2.2.150/home/remoteuser/\" "

Answer (score 0):

When you "run the command separately", you're running it as a user with known permissions and an environment that's set.

```
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

is your hint that the permissions aren't right for the account when it logs in from the code. This isn't a Ruby problem, it's a result of not using the right account, or not setting up the environment; It's outside Ruby.

Comment: if I connect with ssh using "user" in 192.16.58.12 machine, and then perform    rsync -e 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null' --archive -H /home/user/aaaaa remoteuser@10.2.2.150:/home/remoteuser/   -> The copy is well done. This is the same action of my command CMD in Ruby. So, how is it possible that the problem derives from permissions and  environment sets? I'm using the same accounts and, separately, they work.